# How can I convert a list of words into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a txt file of hundreds of thousands of words. I need to get into some format (I think dictionary is the right thing?) where I can put into my script something along the lines of;

```
for i in word_list:
word_length = len(i)
print("Length of " + i + word_length, file=open("LengthOutput.txt", "a"))
```

Currently, the txt file of words is separated by each word being on a new line, if that helps. I've tried importing it to my python script with

```
From x import y
```

.... and similar, but it seems like it needs to be in some format to actually get imported? I've been looking around stackoverflow for a wile now and nothing seems to really cover this specifically but apologies if this is super-beginner stuff that I'm just really not understanding.

Comment: Is every word in a new line? And do hey have to be connected somehow? If each word is individual a list will do fine, no need for a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list would be the correct way to store the words. A dictionary requires a key-value pair and you don't need it in this case.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
     x = [word.strip('\n') for word in file.readlines()]
```

Comment: that's absolutely perfect yeah thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to read a file. An `import` statement is used when you want to, loosely speaking, use python code from another file.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) have a good introduction on reading and writing files -

To read a file, you first open the file, load the contents to memory and finally close the file.

```py
f = open('my_wordfile.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print(len(line))
f.close()
```

A better way is to use the `with` statement and you can find more about that in the docs as well.